# How long does it take to beat vitamin D deficiency

Tags: vitamin-d, sun-exposure, sunlight

I have had vitamin D deficiency (17 ng/mL) and I am planning on sitting in sun at noons. I am aware of that how much UVB you get depends on a few factors such as your complexion, where you live and even the clothes you wear. I know sitting in sun in hot climates can cause sunburn and skin cancer.

The season is winter where I live now. The temperature is around 10 degree celsius but the weather is sunny.

What I was wondering is that if I can beat the vitamin D deficiency in a week if I sit in sun regularly for a few hours for a week.

I know that deficiencies may take for months to return in normal levels such as iron deficiency and you should take a certain amount of it for everyday. However, as for Vitamin D, I read our bodies can accumulate vitamin D in summer times for winter times. Therefore, for my situation, how many days would it take to get to normal level if I sit for long hours regularly in sun.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, people should get enough vitamin D from their food. However, that's difficult to do, Many folks don't get enough of the nutrient from dietary sources like fatty fish and fortified milk.
Ref: [here](https://health-usnews-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/health.usnews.com/wellness/articles/2018-07-18/how-much-time-in-the-sun-do-you-need-for-vitamin-d?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&context=amp&usqp=mq331AQCCAE%3D#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fhealth.usnews.com%2Fwellness%2Farticles%2F2018-07-18%2Fhow-much-time-in-the-sun-do-you-need-for-vitamin-d)

It's not known exactly how much time is needed in the sun to make enough vitamin D to meet the body's requirements.Ref.[here](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/healthy-body/how-to-get-vitamin-d-from-sunlight/)

This is because there are a number of factors that can affect how vitamin D is made, such as your

- skin colour 
  People with dark skin, such as those of African, African-Caribbean or south Asian origin, will need to spend longer in the sun to produce the same amount of vitamin D as someone with lighter skin.
- how much skin you have exposed.
- time of day.
  (Ref.[here](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/healthy-body/how-to-get-vitamin-d-from-sunlight/))

**Risks**

- The American Cancer Society does not support sun exposure for increasing vitamin D. "Because excessive ultraviolet radiation is a major risk factor for skin cancer, we do not recommend obtaining vitamin D from the sun as a way to boost vitamin D levels in the blood," 
  Ref:[here](https://health-usnews-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/health.usnews.com/wellness/articles/2018-07-18/how-much-time-in-the-sun-do-you-need-for-vitamin-d?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&context=amp&usqp=mq331AQCCAE%3D#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fhealth.usnews.com%2Fwellness%2Farticles%2F2018-07-18%2Fhow-much-time-in-the-sun-do-you-need-for-vitamin-d)
- But you should be careful not to burn in the sun, so take care to cover up or protect your skin with sunscreen before your skin starts to turn red or burn.
  Ref.[here](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/healthy-body/how-to-get-vitamin-d-from-sunlight/)

**Balancing Solar risks and benefits:**

There's no risk of your body making too much vitamin D from sun exposure, but always remember to cover up or protect your skin before the time it takes you to start turning red or burn.